# C++ difficulties accessing method from a deep inner class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, methods

I have several classes in my project and some of those classes are the members of other ones. While manipulating the outer class, I would like to access some parameters of its member classes (which could also have their own member classes).

I guess this is not exactly what are "nested classes" in C++, since nested class are being declared within the declaration of the outer class. Then the nested class may not be accessed from the outside of the outer class (just a piece of information for me, to make sure I don't write garbage).

Let’s say I have an AnalogSensor class (handles the behavior of a real analog sensor). This class may have several handlers (one for ADC requests handling, one for filtering incoming data, one for data handling, and the last one for deadzone management).

```
class LinearSpace {
   public:

   // Getters & setters
   private:
      uint16_t min_val; // I'm working with embedded devices
      uint16_t max_val; // Those are values used for linear interpolations
                        // purposes
};


class DataHandler {

   public:
      // Some useful methods
      uint8_t map_raw_data(); // Converts the mapped adc_result (10 bits)
                              // value into an 8-bit, interpolated value
   private:
       LinearSpace input_space;  // Two values spaces used for interpolation
                                 // purposes
       LinearSpace output_space;
};


class AnalogSensor{

   public:
       // "High-Level" methods like void send_adc_request(void);
       // which relies on the internal ADC hander

   private :
      AdcHandler adc_handler;
      DataHandler data_handler;
      Deadzone deadzone;
      DataFilter data_filter;
};
```

Each one of those handlers may rely (or not) on other subclasses, like value ranges (minimum value, maximum value) which has its own getters and setters (getmin, getmax, setmin, and setmax).

Here is an example of what I could end with in my project:

```
AnalogSensor mysensor
   |
    - dataHandler data_handler
      |
       - LinearSpace input_space
      |  |
      |   - min_val
      |  |
      |   - max_val
      |
       - LinearSpace output_space
         |
          - min_val
         |
          - max_val
```

Well, now let’s say I want to modify the minimum and maximuml value of a given range, ***directly from the AnalogSensor class.*** How should I do?

This requirement comes from the necessity to adjust those values for each calibration process (at runtime), as voltages and electronic measurement may vary with time / external conditions such as moisture, etc.

I found many ideas on the Internet:

1. Declare a class as friend (AnalogSensor is the friend of
   AdcHandler and dataFilter, etc...)
2. Declare as much getters and setters inside AnalogSensor which are dedicated to target one specific range (there will be tens of them and I think it is pretty dirty).
3. Or using pointers to access the exact valueRange I want to modify (without
   breaking encapsulation I hope) directly from AnalogSensor class.

In this particular case, I can do something like this:

```
mysensor.getDataHandlerPointer()->getInputSpacePointer()->set_min(my_new_value);
```

How would you do to access those values?

Comment: How about you explain WHY you (and I quote) "want to modify the minimum and maximuml value of a given range, directly from the AnalogSensor class.".     The need to do that, or not, depends on what the AnalogSensor class is required to do.   Without that explanation, there is no context for advising whether the way you have structured your class is appropriate or whether the way you want to set members even makes sense - let alone give advice on suitable methods to do it.

Comment: Actually i'm still looking for a better structure for my classes. My boundaries may change with time (noise in measurements, calibrations, etc.) This may cause the AnalogSensor not to reach the limits of its range, and then  i want to make sure i can tweak and adjust those limits in runtime. 
Maybe it's not necessary to have a dedicated handler to do that, it would be much more easy for me to implement this directly inside AnalogSensor's body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have tens of ranges to change and monitor, it may be wise to store them in (an) array(s), and refer to the ranges by index.  i.e.:

```
struct my_s
{
    enum RangeSpace { input_space, output_space, N_SPACES };

    void setRange(RangeSpace id, int min, int max) { spaces_[id].setMinMax(min, max); }

    // etc...

  private:
    LinearSpace spaces_[N_SPACES];
};
```

Such indexing will optimize nicely when using constants when calling, as in:

```
//...
my_s s;
int a = 0, b = 0;
//...
s.setRange(my_s::input_space, a, b);
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, I will get a special structure which will handle all the ranges of my program? So if I have an AnalogSensor a_sensor; and if I want to access its ranges, I could do something like:
s.setRange(a_sensor.inputSpaceIndex, a,b); ? 
(it's not exactly corresponding to your implementation, but something of that flavour).

That should do the trick. I was thinking of something more 'internal' but that's a good solution. Thanks

Comment: yes.  This kind of structure is also practical when the parameters (or stats) live in static memory, eeprom, etc...  It make serial transfer code less wordy as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like this embedded-friendly solution, as i feel really concerned about optimizing memory and processing power. I'm affraid using too much classes may become heavy for my tiny CPUs to handle (...).

Comment: Glad I could help :)  This tip comes indeed from the embedded side of the Force.